# Why I don't see the directories after login to the vagrant?

Tags: python, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a folder with Python codes in the vagrant folder. So, the directory structure is as following,

vagrant -> restaurant

This is the inside of the vagrant folder that contains vagrantfile and also the restaurant folder,

[image]

The vagrantfile is inside the vagrant folder. I do `vagrant up` and then, `vagrant ssh` and these commands works fine. Afterwards, the terminal asks to `cd /vagrant` and I do that as well. Then, using `ls`, I'm not able to see the `restaurant` folder anymore and unable to enter in the directory. Before It was working just fine.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: can you show you Vagrantfile ? most probably you disabled the sync folder or shared on another folder

Comment: What do you mean by can you show you Vagrantfile ?

Comment: I mean, can you put your Vagrantfile in the question ? there might be a wrong setting in your file as by default Vagrant will share your project directory (the directory with the Vagrantfile) to `/vagrant`. so if the restaurant folder is next to your Vagrantfile on your host it should be in the /vagrant folder on the VM

Comment: I will get back to you in morning, it's 1 AM here

Comment: The vagrantfile is inside the vagrant folder same as the restaurant folder.